# total estimate の表示

Tags: javascript, html

現在費用を計算するページを作成しているのですがtotal estimateの金額がブラウザに表示されません。estimateにidをつけて呼び出してはいるのですが、順序が違うのでしょうか。

コンソールでのエラー表示はありません。どなたか回答よろしくお願いします。

HTML

```
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Fan Trick Fine Art Photography - Estimate</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 999px)" href="fthand.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1000px)" href="fantrick.css" />
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="ftie.css" />
   <![endif]-->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mr+Bedfort' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="container">
      <header>
         <h1>
            <img src="images/ftlogo.png" alt="Fan Trick Fine Art Photography" title="" />
         </h1>
      </header>

      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li id="currentpage"><a href="#">Estimate</a></li>
            <li><a href="digital.htm">Digital 101</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>

      <article>
         <h2>Estimate</h2>
         <p>Our experienced, professional photography team is available to capture memories of your wedding, celebration, or other special event.</p>
         <p>Choose the custom options that fit your needs:</p>
         <form id="estimateform">
            <fieldset>
               <legend><span>Photography</span></legend>
               <input type="number" min="0" max="4" id="photognum" value="1" />
               <label for="photognum">
                  <p># of photographers (1&#8209;4)</p>
                  <p>$100/hr</p>
               </label>

               <input type="number" min="2" id="photoghrs" value="2" />
               <label for="photoghrs">
                  <p># of hours to photograph (minimum&nbsp;2)</p>
               </label>

               <input type="checkbox" id="membook" />
               <label for="membook">
                  <p>Memory book</p>
                  <p>$250</p>
               </label>

               <input type="checkbox" id="reprodrights" />
               <label for="reprodrights">
                  <p>Reproduction rights for all photos</p>
                  <p>$1250</p>
               </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
               <legend><span>Travel</span></legend>
               <input type="number" id="distance" value="0" />
               <label for="distance">
                  <p>Event distance from Austin, TX</p>
                  <p>$1/mi per photographer</p>
               </label>
            </fieldset>
         </form>
      </article>
      <aside>
         <p>Total Estimate: <span id="estimate"></span></p>
      </aside>
      <footer>
         <p>Fan Trick Fine Art Photography &bull; Austin, Texas</p>
      </footer>
   </div>
   <script src="ft.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var photographerCost = 0;
var totalCost = 0;
var memoryBook = false;
var reproductionRights = false;
function calcStaff(){
  var num = document.getElementById("photognum");
  var hrs = document.getElementById("photoghrs");
  var distance = document.getElementById("distance");
  totalCost -= photographerCost;
  photographerCost = num.value * 100 * hrs.value + distance.value * num.value;
  totalCost += photographerCost;
  document.getElementById("estimate").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}
  function toggleMembook(){
    (document.getElementById("membook").checked === false)?
    totalCost -= 250 : totalCost += 250;
    document.getElementById("estimate").innerHTML = "$"+ totalCost;
}
function toggleRights(){
  (document.getElementById("reprodrights").checked === false)?
  totalCost -= 1250 : totalCost += 1250;
  document.getElementById("estimate").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}
function resetForm(){
  document.getElementById("photognum").value=1;
  document.getElementById("photoghrs").value=2;
  document.getElementById("membook").checked=memoryBook;
  document.getElementById("reprodrights").checked=reproductionRights;
  document.getElementById("distance").value=0;
  calcStaff();
  createEventListeners();
}
function createEventListeners(){
  document.getElementById("photognum").
  addEventListener("change", calcStaff, false);
  document.getElementById("photoghrs").
  addEventListener("change",calcStaff,false);
  document.getElementById("membook").
   addEventListener("change",toggleMembook, false);
   document.getElementById("reprodrights").
    addEventListener("change", toggleRights, false);
  document.getElementById("distance").
    addEventListener("change", calcStaff, false);
}
```

Comment: `resetForm()` 関数が実行されていませんので`window.onload = resetForm;` を追加するとよろしいかと。

Comment: @metropolis  表示されました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: 解決したようであれば、コメント欄で終わらせずにぜひ **個別の回答** として投稿してみてください。